# JQuery fullscreen image resize issue in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, resize, fullscreen

First I'd like to thank the kind people that helped me out a month ago with a question I had.
I'm almost there but am having a problem with an image resize on this page.

http://www.designbyantony.com/David%20Quigley%20www/index.html

The JQuery resize on the homepage works fine in Firefox. In Safari the height doesn't seem to want to work and I'm left with a blank white area underneath the image when the window is resized.
I haven't tested this in IE - I would be really grateful if somebody would just check to see if it fails here too.

I am a complete JQuery newbie so any help would be really appreciated.

Antony

Comment: could u supply us the code? especially the CSS and the jQuery code you used. :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually, scratch my comment. I checked your code through firebug and I saw that you are using an img tag. You could try to do this:

Delete the img tag. Your preferred method is not working in chrome as well. Put this css code on your body tag:

```
body {
background-image:url('images/bg3.jpg');
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:0,0;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Hi AJ - thanks very much for responding. This works great on this page, however the background images now shows up on the other site pages (which I don't want - they are just meant to be white). Any ideas?

Comment: I wondered if each page should have an ID or have a selector of some sort? Just pulling thimgs out of the air obviously!

Comment: u can use inline styles for that particular page like <body style=""> or u can also use the <style> tag for the <head> e.g <style>body { } </style>

Comment: AJ - you're a star, thank you so much. Works a treat. Antony :)

Comment: np. Don't forget to vote up if the answers helped you. Good luck :)